# Quick Sort in Python

Tags: python

Ok, I have edited my code again, thanks to the comment below. But still it doesn't work peoperly...Please help.

Edited:

```
import random
def quickSort(A,start,size): # randomized version
 if size<2:
     return
 pivot=A[int(random.choice(A[start:start+size])
 L=start
 U=L+size-1
 while L<U:
     while A[L]<pivot:
         L+=1
     while A[U]>pivot:
         U-=1
     A[L],A[U]=A[U],A[L]
 quickSort(A,start,L)
 quickSort(A,L+1,size-L-1)

 A=[22,77,55,33,88,11] 
 quickSort(A,0,6)
 print A
```

Previous Post:

I have implemented a quick sort in Python. Below is the implementation. But it does not sort correctly. It seems that the original array A does not get affected with the recursions in some steps.

Please help. Thanks!

```
import random

def quickSort(A,size): # randomized version
     if size<2:
         return
     pivot=A[int(random.uniform(0,size))%size]
     L=0
     U=size-1
     while L<U:
         while A[L]<pivot:
             L+=1
         while A[U]>pivot:
             U-=1
         A[L],A[U]=A[U],A[L]
     quickSort(A,L)
     quickSort(A[L:],size-L-1)

A=[33,50,18,2,66] 
quickSort(A,5)
print A
```

Comment: Looks like you could simplify `pivot` to `random.choice(A)`. Anyways, you’re using `return` twice, when you should not be using it at all. `return` terminates the execution of a function.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the return statements! I just realized I had to delete the return statements but still code doesn't sort the array properly. I will definitely use the random choice from now on! :)

Comment: And yes, the slice created from `A[L:]` doesn’t reference `A`. You could add a `start` argument in addition to `size`.

Comment: minitech: how would I reference A in A[L:]? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @minitech, what does it _reference_?

Comment: @paris: You can’t; you need to keep passing `A` around. (Well, you could create a new class and overload the slice operator for it, but passing around `A` and boundary information is simpler.)

Comment: @wwii: I’m not really sure what your question is, here, or why the emphasis is on “reference”.

Comment: @minitech: Thank you! I am working on it now to add a start variable and pass around A.

Comment: @wwii, `A[L:]` references a copy of that part of `A`. Making inplace changes to `A[L:]` will have no effect on `A`

Comment: @paris Is it a requirement of yours to sort `A` in place?

Comment: Ahhh-thankyou I did not understand what minitech was saying, but then I was trying to wrap my head around the two return statements in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `quickSort(A,0,L)` has hard coded start at position `0` when it should start at `start`, the same place L began (`L=start`).

Then your ??? can be `start+size-1` just like where `U` began.

And adjust your `random.uniform(..)` call, because it's asking for a range starting at a *position* and finishing at a *number of items* - it will go backwards, e.g. *starting at 50 and ending at 8*. That needs to be `start, start+size` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Let's quote Jon Bentley (“Programming Pearls”, Addison-Wesley, 1986, footnote on page 110):

> Most presentations of Quicksort use a partitioning scheme based on two
>   approaching indices, … . Although the basic idea of that scheme is
>   simple, I have always found the details tricky — I once spent the
>   better part of two days chasing down a bug hiding in a short
>   partitioning loop. A reader of a preliminary draft complained that the
>   standard two-index method is in fact simpler than Lomuto’s, and
>   sketched some code to make his point; I stopped looking after I found
>   two bugs.

You are using the *approaching indices* scheme, aren't you?

And here it is Nico Lomuto's partitioning in all its beauty, together with a bit of testing

```
from random import randrange

def order(A, L, U):

    p = randrange(L,U+1)
    A[L], A[p] = A[p], A[L]
    V = A[L]
    print "# random value:", V
    M = L
    for K in range(L, U+1):
        if A[K]<V:
            M = M+1
            A[M], A[K] = A[K], A[M]
    A[L], A[M] = A[M], A[L]
    return M

N = 20
for i in range(10):
    l = [randrange(0,10) for _ in range(N)]
    s = order(l,0,N-1)
    print "#", l[:s], [l[s]], l[s+1:]
```

producing

```
# random value: 5
# [2, 3, 4, 1, 0, 1, 1, 4, 0, 4, 0, 1, 4] [5] [9, 5, 7, 6, 9, 9]
# random value: 2
# [0, 0, 0, 1, 1] [2] [7, 3, 2, 6, 5, 8, 7, 8, 4, 4, 3, 9, 8, 6]
# random value: 8
# [2, 5, 3, 1, 5, 4, 2, 2, 3, 5, 0, 6, 3, 2, 2] [8] [8, 9, 8, 9]
# random value: 5
# [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 4] [5] [7, 8, 9, 5, 9, 9, 9, 8, 9, 8, 7, 9]
# random value: 7
# [2, 0, 5, 2, 1, 4, 4, 4, 5, 3, 2, 1, 0, 4, 6, 5, 3] [7] [9, 9]
# random value: 4
# [2, 2, 1, 0, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2] [4] [4, 4, 9, 9, 6, 6, 9]
# random value: 6
# [4, 2, 5, 5, 0, 1, 4, 3, 0, 0] [6] [9, 8, 9, 7, 8, 9, 6, 9, 8]
# random value: 3
# [0, 2, 1, 0, 2] [3] [3, 4, 6, 9, 3, 8, 4, 8, 9, 8, 3, 3, 7, 9]
# random value: 5
# [0, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 0] [5] [6, 6, 5, 8, 5, 7, 5, 8, 5, 5]
# random value: 6
# [0, 5, 2, 1, 1, 0, 3, 3, 0] [6] [7, 9, 6, 6, 6, 9, 6, 9, 8, 6]
```

I think that with a bit of effort on your part you can write a correct implementation of quicksort.

PS: it is possible that the campus library has a copy of Bentley's book, well I found it a very pleasant reading...